# Insert Into Select SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do a kind of insert into select statement. I want to insert one column as standard and the second through a select. However this is not working:

```
queryString = "INSERT INTO Words (Word, SortedId) VALUES ('" + words[i] + "', (SELECT TOP 1 SortedId FROM SortedWords WHERE SortedWord = '" + sortWord(words[i]) + "'))";
```

SortedWords is already filled with data. But at the moment i get this error

```
{"There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 50,Token in error = SELECT ]"}
```

Note:

not sure if i need the TOP 1 bit or not, get error either way. But I obvs only want to insert one row.

Comment: It's not clear where `queryString` is being assigned, or where you're passing it to SQL Server and the parsing is failing, but somewhere immediately after `queryString` use a messagebox or print statement to see what it actually contains. You should also research *parameterized queries* for whatever language you're using; your code is wide open for SQL injection and other problems.

Answer (score 2):

Try next and better practice to use a SqlParameters:

```
INSERT INTO words 
            (word, 
             sortedid) 
(SELECT TOP 1 @Word, 
              sortedid 
 FROM   sortedwords 
 WHERE  sortedword = @SortedWord)
```

And before execiting query create a parameters(C#)

```
//Assume you have a SqlCommand object(lets name it command)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Word", words[i]);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SortedWord", sortWord(words[i]));
```

Comment: executing with db.Query(queryString) - would this still apply

Comment: Show your function `db.Query`.I think you will need to change your `db.Query` function to use parameters or just add a new one with SqlParameters as function parameter

Answer (score 2):

Change your query to

```
queryString = "INSERT INTO Words (Word, SortedId) SELECT '" + words[i] + "', (SELECT TOP 1 SortedId FROM SortedWords WHERE SortedWord = '" + sortWord(words[i]) + "')";
```

Also, instead of concatenating strings to get your query, use parameters to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: This is still throwing an error - executing like so db.Query(queryString);

Comment: It works for me... What is your `queryString` when you execute it?

Comment: exactly what you posted ^ im using asp.net with c# if that helps at all?

Comment: I wanted to know what you have in `words[i]`. When I entered `a`, it worked for me. And what is the error?

Comment: words would be looping through the array with things like "cat", "truck", "fire" and the error is:
{"There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 49,Token in error = SELECT ]"}

Comment: Does that query work for you from SQL Server Management Studio?